# How to share Bluetooth received data among multiple activities in one application

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an application which has 5 different tabs, Now i have Bluetooth connectivity in my first tab activity. This activity receives data from other device and display. But this connection is not helpful for the other tabs activity in the same application.

I want your suggestion how to achieve Bluetooth connectivity for all the activities in the same application.So that i can receive data from other device and display that information in all the respective predefined activities.

Please comment on this.

do u think this can be achieved by a service running in background and pushing the received data to the activity.? If yes then How?

Or if you have any other suggestion then please share them asap.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) link to make bluetooth connections and a class named ConnectedThreads requires some handler to communicate with UI,
U can try changing chat handler as and when activity changes and it will send msg to which ever activity in front.

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your informative reply but can you please tell me how can i update all 5 activities UI even if are are in background. Like I want to keep those activities screen updated always.

Comment: u can set 5 different handlers and send msg to all of them