# How to update View Pager with Bluetooth received values?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with a few fragments. By default when the activity starts I start `Bluetooth` and connect to a known device. When the bluetooth device sends data, the data is shown in a text view in that fragment. For that I use a `Handler`.

The problem is that if I switch to the second tab/page/fragment, the values are still shown in the previous fragment, because the thread is still running and the `Handler` is still updating this `TextView`.

I can cancel and start the Bluetooth `ConnectThread` every time I switch between the pages/fragments, but I think that there should be a more efficient solution.
Also this doesn't help if at some point I need to reload the view pager.

So my question is: is it possible to have something (Handler) that updates the text views of the currently active page/fragment?

I found this question to be similar: [How to share Bluetooth received data among multiple activities in one application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185746/how-to-share-bluetooth-received-data-among-multiple-activities-in-one-applicatio) but it didn't help me find out..

My `Handler` looks like that:

```
static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<MyFragment> mFragment;

        public MyHandler(MyFragment fragment) {
            mFragment = new WeakReference<>(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            MyFragment fragment = mFragment.get();
            if (fragment != null) {
                String tempValue = (String) msg.obj;
                if (tempValue != null && !tempValue.equals("")) {
                    try {
                          fragment.setValuesFromBluetooth(tempValue.trim());
                          // here i need something to update the current active fragment
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //log
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void setValuesFromBluetooth(String value) {
        tv1.setText(value);
}
```

**EDIT**: I am attaching an image illustrating of what I am trying to do/achieve.

[image: bluetooth-handler-activity-fragments-image]